# WebStorm, reset work item timer?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How can I reset the timer on this work item?

[image]

The "Show time spent from last post of work item" works if you use WebStorm's "Post Time" button, but I did a commit last night and logged the work in the commit message (`#time 2h`).

How can I just reset the timer?